# MongoDB 32 Bit Master Node

Tags: mongodb

I know that if you run MongoDB on a 32 bit operating system it can only store up to 2 GB of data. Does this restriction apply to a master node in a MongoDB cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe. In master-slave setup, the master receives all the writes and the other slaves simply replicate from the master. So the master is the one where the following restrictions apply.  From the [FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#what-are-the-limitations-of-32-bit-versions-of-mongodb)

> MongoDB uses memory-mapped files. When running a 32-bit build of
>   MongoDB, the total storage size for the server, including data and
>   indexes, is 2 gigabytes. For this reason, do not deploy MongoDB to
>   production on 32-bit machines.